# Special alignment of equations in an optimization problem

Tags: equations, amsmath, aligned

In the following problem, I would like to align the `y` in the fourth equation with the `y` in the third equation.

This question may seem obvious, but I'm still struggling with equation alignment in a long write-up. It may also seem similar to previous questions I asked, but none of the solutions worked. I tried to play with `&`, `\mathrlap`, and `\phantom` with no success.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{extbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \[  \begin{aligned}
        &\text{minimize}   &J(y) &= \int_a^b f \big(x,y(x),y'(x) \big) \mathrm{d} x \\
        &\text{subject to} & y(a) &= \alpha, \\
        && y(b) &= \beta, \\
        &&& y \in C^1[a,b].
    \end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that `y(b)` is narrower (width-wise) than `y(a)` and `J(y)` (where the latter is the widest element that is used to align the relations). However, aesthetically, it's probably better to align the `y`'s closest to one another:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    &\text{minimize}   & J(y) &= \int_a^b f \bigl( x, y(x), y'(x) \bigr) \mathrm{d} x \\
    &\text{subject to} & y(a) &= \alpha,                                            \\
    &                  & y(b) &= \beta,                                             \\
    &                  & \mathrlap{y \in C^1[a, b].}\phantom{y(b)}
  \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

The alignment is achieved in the following way: The entire fourth row *visible* content is set in a zero-width box that overlaps to the `r`ight (is left-aligned). And, to the right of this zero-width box, we "fake set" `y(b)`. This allows the width of the space to be taken up be exactly like `y(b)`, but only setting the zero-width box content visually.

Comment: Thank you, @Werner, as always.

Comment: @AEW: Hopefully it makes sense, by looking at the code, how the alignment is achieved. For completeness, the entire fourth row *visible* content is set in a zero-width box that overlaps to the `r`ight (is left-aligned). And, to the right of this zero-width box, we "fake set" `y(b)`. This allows the width of the space to be taken up exactly like `y(b)`, but only setting the zero-width box content visually.

Comment: Yes, I have a better understanding of the solution now. I hope you could keep the comments. Thank you for all your help with this.

Comment: @AEW: I've added the comment explaining the alignment process to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest three ways.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{alignat}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
& \text{minimize}   &\quad& J(y) && = \int_a^b f \bigl( x, y(x), y'(x) \bigr) \diff x \\
& \text{subject to} &     & y(a) && = \alpha, \\
&                   &     & y(b) && = \beta, \\
&                   &     & \mathrlap{y \in C^1[a, b].}
\end{alignat*}

Simpler with \texttt{IEEEeqnarray}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{l'lCl}
\text{minimize}   & J(y) &=& \int_a^b f \bigl( x, y(x), y'(x) \bigr) \diff x \\
\text{subject to} & y(a) &=& \alpha, \\
                  & y(b) &=& \beta, \\
                  & \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}{y \in C^1[a, b].}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

Without forced alignments
\begin{alignat*}{2}
& \text{minimize}   &\quad& J(y) = \int_a^b f \bigl( x, y(x), y'(x) \bigr) \diff x \\
& \text{subject to} &     &
  \begin{alignedat}[t]{2} & y(a) &&=\alpha, \\ & y(b) &&=\beta, \end{alignedat} \\
&                   &     & y \in C^1[a, b].
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\bigl` and `\bigr`, not the unadorned `\big`. Also `\diff` as defined provides better spacing (and it's easy to change all those awful upright d's into proper italic).